# Erro ao usar o Selenium WebDriver no Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Estou tentando desenvolver um *script* em Python que simplesmente abra o navegador como mostrado nesse site [Selenium com o Chrome](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started), mas toda vez que tento rodar o programa me deparo com o seguinte erro:

> navegator = webdriver.Chrome() AttributeError: module
>   'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Segue abaixo o code completo:

```
from selenium import webdriver driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Program
Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
```

IDE: PyCharm.

OBS: Já baixei o ChromeDriver e reinstalei o Selenium varias vezes.

Answer (score 0):

Usei exatamente esse código do [link](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) que enviaste. 
Estou a usar o visual studio com a versão 3.6 do Python. Neste basta-te isntalar o selenium via pip e fazer o download do chrome driver. Extrais o exe e poes numa pasta à escolha. Eu pus numa pata chamada "C:\Bin". O código resultante é identico ao teu mas com a diferença de que deves apontar para o chrome driver e não para o exe do chrome.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Bin\chromedriver.exe')
```

O Podes encontrar o driver para download aqui: [na página do google para esse efeito.](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mas já tentei isso e resulta no mesmo erro                                                       <<driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')>> Será um problema do Pycharm ?, outra duvida você adicionou o ChromeDriver ao PATH?
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver' has no attribute 'Chrome'

Answer (score 0):

Segue o código que utilizo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')
self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

Se atente a utilizar duas barras no path.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, não era esse o problema e sim faltava adicionar o modulo do selenium nas configurações do PyCharm, deve ser um erro de iniciante em Python kkkk, mas obrigado